# Unknown display error

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have recently installation Ubuntu 16.04.
I found that my monitor is not being detected for 16:9 ratio displays. 
I have also tried one of the solution on net and able to add 1360x768 display via "xrandr". it worked fine but after restarting PC I am back on square one.
How can i set 16:9 resolution permanently on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: i am using VGA cable for display.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` to your question. Also check if there is a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. If that file exists, move it `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig` and reboot.

Comment: @Thomas ... chahil@chahil-home-pc:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-58-generic root=UUID=e9aff396-b3de-48b2-a259-c08c10c0f878 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7.  Also there is no /etc directory